# Add template to sidebar

Tags: magento-2.1

I have made a theme, lets call it `Mytheme/custom`. I want to add a `.phtml` file to the sidebar. How do I do that?

I have already made this but it doesn't work:

`Mytheme/custom/Magento_Catalog/layout/default.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="seotext_sidebar"
                   template="Mytheme_Custom::product/sidebar/seotext.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

`Mytheme/custom/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/sidebar/seotext.phtml`

`<h1>test</h1>`

Also I want the current category information be available to `seotext.phtml` should I change `Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template` to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update xml file as follows.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.additional">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="seotext_sidebar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/sidebar/seotext.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Note: Correction in 
`template="Mytheme_Custom::product/sidebar/seotext.phtml"`

Comment: It doesn't work for me yet, but I need to test a couple of things though. Will accept it if it works. Might be the "Infortis" theme interfer with the code.